# Spark collect_list change data_type from array to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collect, lis

I am having a following aggregation

```scala
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"a",$"b",$"c")
    .agg(sum($"d").alias("data1"),sum($"e").alias("data2"))
    .groupBy($"a")
    .agg(collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data1")).alias("final_data1"),
         collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data2")).alias("final_data2"))
```

Here I am doing some aggregation and collecting the result with `collect_list`. Earlier we were using spark 1 and it was giving me below data types.

```
 |-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- final_data2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Now we have to migrate to spark 2 but we are getting below schema.

```
|-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

On getting `first()` record below is the difference

```
spark 1.6

[2020-09-26, Ayush, 103.67] => datatype string

spark 2 

WrappedArray(2020-09-26, Ayush, 103.67)
```

How can I keep the same data type?

**Edit - Tried Using Concat**

One way I got exact schema like Spark 1.6 is by using concat like this

```
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"msisdn",$"event_date",$"network")
    .agg(sum($"data_mou").alias("data_mou_dly"),sum($"voice_mou").alias("voice_mou_dly"))
    .groupBy($"msisdn")
    .agg(collect_list(concat(lit("["),lit($"event_date"),lit(","),lit($"network"),lit(","),lit($"data_mou_dly"),lit("]")))
```

Will it affect my code performance?? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a way to generate a sample dataframe? Because right now I do not manage to reproduce your output with spark 1.6. I get an Exception.

Comment: you can create sample data like below
a = any number for aggregate ( like serial number of candidate)
b = date
c = region like ( state codes)
d = float values ( consider marks obtained per 100)
e = same as d

Comment: @Oli I have edited my question. Do you think this is a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a string representation of an array, how about casting the array into a string like this?

```scala
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"a",$"b",$"c")
    .agg(sum($"d").alias("data1"),sum($"e").alias("data2"))
    .groupBy($"a")
    .agg(collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data1") cast "string").alias("final_data1"),
         collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data2") cast "string").alias("final_data2"))
```

It might simply be what your old version of spark was doing.

The solution you propose would probably work as well by the way but wrapping your column references with `lit` is not necessary (`lit($"event_date")`). `$"event_date"` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Fllttening final1 and final2 columns would fix this problem.

```
val data = Seq((1,"A", "B"), (1, "C", "D"), (2,"E", "F"), (2,"G", "H"), (2,"I", "J"))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  data
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

val old_df = df.groupBy(col("col1")).agg(
    collect_list(
        array(
            col("col2"), 
            col("col3")
            )
    ).as("final")
    )
val new_df = old_df.select(col("col1"), flatten(col("final")).as("final_new"))
println("Input Dataframe")

df.show(false)
println("Old schema format")
old_df.show(false)
old_df.printSchema()

println("New schema format")
new_df.show(false)
new_df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
Input Dataframe
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |A   |B   |
|1   |C   |D   |
|2   |E   |F   |
|2   |G   |H   |
|2   |I   |J   |
+----+----+----+

Old schema format
+----+------------------------+
|col1|final                   |
+----+------------------------+
|1   |[[A, B], [C, D]]        |
|2   |[[E, F], [G, H], [I, J]]|
+----+------------------------+

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- final: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

New schema format
+----+------------------+
|col1|final_new         |
+----+------------------+
|1   |[A, B, C, D]      |
|2   |[E, F, G, H, I, J]|
+----+------------------+

root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- final_new: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

In you specefic case

```
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"a",$"b",$"c")
    .agg(sum($"d").alias("data1"),sum($"e").alias("data2"))
    .groupBy($"a")
    .agg(collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data1")).alias("final_data1"),
         collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data2")).alias("final_data2"))
         .select(flatten(col("final_data1").as("final_data1"), flatten(col("final_data2).as("final_data2))
```

Comment: There is some misunderstanding . we don't have to mix those wrappedarray into one. I want to get it in the same datatype as in spark 1.6 which is string in format [[E,F],[G,H],[I,J]]
. Here [I,J] is one string, same for [G,H] and [I,J].