# Spark 2 converting scala array to WrappedArray

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark 2 is converting scala array to WrappedArray automatically When i am passing array to function. However, In Spark 1.6 array is converted to string like  '[a,b,c]' . Here is my code

```
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"a",$"b",$"c")
    .agg(sum($"d").alias("data1"),sum($"e").alias("data2"))
    .groupBy($"a")
    .agg(collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data1")).alias("final_data1"),
         collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data2")).alias("final_data2"))
```

When I am running above code to spark 1.6. I am getting below schema

```
 |-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- final_data2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

but in spark 2

```
|-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- final_data1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I change datatype of spark 2 as per spark 1?

Comment: I believe you have posted twice the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204751/spark-collect-list-change-data-type-from-array-to-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a string representation of an array, how about casting the array into a string like this?

```scala
val df_date_agg = df
    .groupBy($"a",$"b",$"c")
    .agg(sum($"d").alias("data1"),sum($"e").alias("data2"))
    .groupBy($"a")
    .agg(collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data1") cast "string").alias("final_data1"),
         collect_list(array($"b",$"c",$"data2") cast "string").alias("final_data2"))
```

It might simply be what your old version of spark was doing. I was not able to verify.